# How to hook up two viewsets to a single django url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I hava a standard DRF viewset for a model which I hook up in my `urls.py` as such:

```py
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register("", ResourceViewSet, basename="resource")

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "",
        include(router.urls),
        name="basic-resource-crud",
    ),
]
```

Resource is the only model in the app so it is hooked up to the root. Additionally I would like to hook up the `PATCH` method on the root url to a bulk update view:

```py
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register("", ResourceViewSet, basename="notifications")

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "",
        BulkResourceUpdateViewSet.as_view(),
        name="bulk-resource-update",
    ),
    path(
        "",
        include(router.urls),
        name="basic-resource-crud",
    ),
]
```

The `BulkResourceUpdateViewSet` class only defines a `patch` method.

However with the setup above only the first route in the `urlpatterns` array is taken into considereation by Django and the other is ignored.

How can I achive the url structure I am looking for:

```
GET   /      : ResourceViewSet
PATCH /      : BulkResourceUpdateViewSet.patch
GET   /<pk>/ : ResourceViewSet
POST  /<pk>/ : ResourceViewSet
PATCH /<pk>/ : ResourceViewSet
PUT   /<pk>/ : ResourceViewSet
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not have URLs of a ViewSet defined like this. DRF ensures giving you cleaner URLs depending on the methods in your `ViewSet`. You can include the `bulk-update` action within your ViewSet, as it is modifying the same resource. This makes your URL scheme consistent with REST API standards and generates a cleaner URL schema.

Something like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers, mixins, status, viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response

from your_app.models import Resource
from your_app.serializers import ResourceSerializer

class ResourceViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                      mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                      mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Resource.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResourceSerializer
    
    @action(methods=['PATCH'], detail=False)
    def bulk_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Your bulk update logic here
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In your `urls.py` file, you can add the routes via simple route like:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('', ResourceViewSet, basename='resource')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This would ensure that the following routes are added:

- `GET /`       - List of resources
- `POST /`      - Create a new resource
- `GET /:pk/`   - Get a single resource depending on `pk`
- `PATCH /:pk/` - Modify single resource identified by `pk`
- `PUT /:pk/`   - Modify single resource identified by `pk` with all-attributes
- `PATCH /bulk-update/` - Bulk update resources

Ideally, even if you have got a single resource in your project, you should have the URLs prefixed on the root of `api/` with the resource name. This makes your project extendible.

So, the URLs should be like this:

`GET /api/resource_name/` instead of `GET /` for getting the list of resources, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add this functionality in the current ViewSet without changing the urls (if you do not want to do monkey patch solutions). If you are willing to change the url, then you can add this functionality in the ViewSet like this:

```
class ResourceViewSet(...):
    
     @action(detail=False)
     def bulk_update(self, request):
         ...
```

Otherwise, you can have one view with List and Update functionality, and another viewset with rest of the functionality, like this:

```
class BulkResourceListUpdateView(ListAPIView):
   # bulk update codes here         

class ResourceViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):

     ....
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/).